# Getting TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.btn-create-post-card').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let form_data = new FormData(),
      file = $('.input_file_button');
    // if(!file.val()) {
    //     alert('Please select postcard you want to send')
    // }
    form_data.append("file", file.prop('files')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/sendEmail",
      dataType: 'multipart/form-data',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('OK');
      },
      error: function(error, status) {
        console.log('here');
        console.log(error);
        alert(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be
> accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls
> to them 
>     at Function.remoteFunction (:2:14)

Console output is: [image]

As you can see the response is successful and I've used jQuery AJAX calls a lot before and never had this issue.

**Updated:**

console output:

```
abort: ƒ (e)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 1
    name: "abort"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
always: ƒ ()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 0
    name: "always"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
catch: ƒ (e)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 1
    name: "catch"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
done: ƒ ()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 0
    name: "add"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
fail: ƒ ()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 0
    name: "add"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 0
    name: "getAllResponseHeaders"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 1
    name: "getResponseHeader"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 1
    name: "overrideMimeType"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
pipe: ƒ ()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 0
    name: "pipe"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
progress: ƒ ()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 0
    name: "add"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
promise: ƒ (e)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 1
    name: "promise"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
readyState: 4
responseText: ""can't upload file""
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 2
    name: "setRequestHeader"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
state: ƒ ()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 0
    name: "state"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (e)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 1
    name: "statusCode"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
statusText: "OK"
then: ƒ (t,r,i)
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
    length: 3
    name: "then"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Please share the actual output of the console instead of an image of it.

Comment: are you using `strict mode`

Comment: I found that strict mode is used in jquery, but I'm not using it in my code

Comment: Are you transforming your code with babel or webpack? If so, "use strict" might leak into other parts of the code depending on how it's configured. Do you happen to know which library adds the `remoteFunction()` method to the Function prototype? Is that part of JQuery? You might have to isolate that module. Caller, callee and arguments cannot be used in strict mode, so alot of libraries that rely on these have to be updated or isolated from any scopes that have "use strict".

Comment: nope, I'm not using babel and webpack, I'm just adding scripts directly to the page (it's a simple app, no need to configure webpack for it). 

I'm using:
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>

Comment: I just search for keyword `remoteFunction` and no results...

Comment: btw, it was work yesterday on another machine but I'm not sure how different env can affect it as I'm using same scripts

Comment: I remove all usages of `use strict` in `jquery` and in `slick` but issue is still exist

Comment: Also remove 'type=module'. Worked for me by doing that

Answer (score 10):

I don't think strict mode is the error, it's just that the console can't get the contents of the arguments array in strict mode. The status is 200 so it looks like the ajax call worked, but the response text says "can't upload file", so I think the error is on the server side.

Update with TypeError example:

That TypeError just says the console can't get the values the arguments array when using strict mode. It's not an error with the code. The simple example in the image demonstrates this.

[image: Example of TypeError]

Comment: well, "can't upload file" it's just a dummy message, for now. It's hardcoded message. So I do not see how it can affect.

Comment: It looks like your ajax call is working. That TypeError is not an error with your code.

Comment: Maybe I need to add dome specific header to response? I set ContentType to applicatiin/json and body is json string. So looks likevrequest is good and code is okay

Answer (score 8):

I found the issue: it was in `dataType: 'multipart/form-data'` and, after I remove it, everything is working.

I think it worked on a different machine because the browser version on that machine does not support `strict mode`.

Answer (score 5):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller:

> If the function f was invoked by the top-level code, the value of
> f.caller is null; otherwise it's the function that called f. If the
> function that called f is a strict mode function, the value of
> f.caller is also null.
>
> In strict mode, accessing caller of a function throws an error. This
> is to prevent a function from being able to "walk the stack", which
> both poses security risks and severely limits the possibility of
> optimizations like inlining and tail-call optimization. For more
> explanation, you can read the rationale for the deprecation of
> arguments.callee.
>
> Note that the only behavior specified by the ECMAScript specification
> is that Function.prototype has an initial caller accessor that
> unconditionally throws a TypeError for any get or set request (known
> as a "poison pill accessor"), and that implementations are not allowed
> to change this semantic for any function except non-strict plain
> functions, in which case it must not have the value of a strict mode
> function. The actual behavior of the caller property, if it's anything
> other than throwing an error, is implementation-defined. For example,
> Chrome defines it as an own data property, while Firefox and Safari
> extend the initial poison-pill Function.prototype.caller accessor to
> specially handle this values that are non-strict functions.