# iOS Safari 13.3.1 uploaded file size is 0

Tags: file-upload, safari, upload, jquery-file-upload, form-data

I have simple-page site on PHP, where users can upload file (stl-model).
At first I was use for upload JS `FormData`. It's work in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari iOS sometimes send file with size = 0 bytes.
JS console.log show, that file size 718120 bytes before send. PHP debug mode show that global `$ _FILE` exists and file name is true, but file is empty:

```
(
    [name] => TRRSExtenderMount.stl
    [type] => application / octet-stream
    [tmp_name] => / tmp / phphDceFc
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 0
)
```

The error with size 0 repeats from time to time.

What I tried:

- checked phpinfo post_max_size, upload_max_filesize
- tested on different devices (all with 13.3.1 iOS)
- tested with different stl-files and file-size (from 0.5mb to 16mb)
- tested with 3g, 4g and wi-fi
- checked slow upload speed: check file size, wait 10 seconds and check it again
- changed input form for standart HTML with POST method without JS

But the error was repeated again. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

So, I fixed this problem. May be my experience can help somebody:

1. I reproduced that error returns when you repeat Ajax call 2 min later that first call if you don't reload page.
2. I noticed File object attribute "lastModified" always equal to file creation date. So browser may be used Formdata from cache. I added next code to always send "new" file:

```
    this.trueFile = new File([this.originalFile], 'file-name.stl', {lastModified: new Date()});
```

3. After that the error changed: second Ajax call (after 2 min) crashed on timeout and returned next message:

```
    TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode
```

4. Next step I found this question: [Getting TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298691/getting-typeerror-caller-callee-and-arguments-properties-may-not-be-acc) , And delete next row: 
   `dataType: 'json'` from my code. And it helped.