# Data table on server Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

Data table runs fine on local but when i have published on server its Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "testing.asmx/Get_DashBoardData",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#MO').dataTable({
            data: data,
            "bInfo": false, //Dont display info e.g. "Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries"
            "paging": false,//Dont want paging                
            "bPaginate": false,//Dont want paging   
            "bFilter": false, //hide Search bar
            columns: [
                { 'data': 'abc' },
                { 'data': 'cde' },
            ]
        });
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

but I get the exception as below:

> **Exception:** TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties
>   may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects
>   for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (:1:142)]
>
> Internal Server Error jquery.min.js:2 [Violation] 'load' handler took
>   21304ms jquery.min.js:2 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 5863ms

Comment: Welcome @user3004207. Could you please read this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298691/getting-typeerror-caller-callee-and-arguments-properties-may-not-be-acc) for some references?

Comment: I have tried that doesn't help ..

Comment: Did you get the console log message out? Post it here please.