# I am writing a client side code to retreive a record but facing the below issue

Tags: typeerror

I am writing this code using Xrm.Webapi.RetreiveRecord as below but I am getting the below error when debugging.

TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

if (typeof (ContosoPermit) == "undefined") { var ContosoPermit = { __namespace: true }; }
if (typeof (ContosoPermit.Scripts) == "undefined") { ContosoPermit.Scripts = { __namespace: true }; }

ContosoPermit.Scripts.PermitForm = {

```
handleOnLoad: function (executionContext) {

    console.log('on load - permit form');

},

    handleOnChangePermitType: function (executionContext)

    {
        console.log('on change - permit type');

},

_handlePermitTypeSettings: function (executionContext) {
    
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); 
    var permitType = formContext.getAttribute("contoso_permittype").getValue();
    if (permitType == null) {
        formContext.ui.tabs.get("inspectionsTab").setVisible(false);
        return;
    } else {
        var permitTypeID = permitType[0].id;
        
         
        
        debugger;
        
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("contoso_permittype", permitTypeID).then(

            function success(result) {
            if (result.contoso_requireinspections) {
                formContext.ui.tabs.get("inspectionstab").setVisible(true);

            }
            else {
                formContext.ui.tabs.get("inspectionstab").setVisible(false);

            }
        },
            function (error) { alert('Error' + error.message) });

    }
},


__namespace: true
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298691/getting-typeerror-caller-callee-and-arguments-properties-may-not-be-acc)

Comment: Unfortunately no